# PostGIS - ST_Difference creates extra line segment

Tags: postgis, differences

I have some line of sights from one point, collected into a multilinestring. I want to cut the multilinestring using PostGIS' ST_Difference and a border-dataset (a single multipolygon).

I used this query:

```
select a.id, 
       st_makevalid(st_multi(st_difference(a.geom, b.geom))) geom
        from lineofsight a, 
        border b
```

When i cut the dataset, it behaves mostly as I expected, as the part of the multilinestring crossing the border gets removed.

### start input

(green lines are the multilinestring, the brown/grayish area is the border-polygon)
[image]

### after ST_Difference:

[image]

### the issue

Inspecting the result from ST_Difference, I have noticed that it sometimes creates short linestrings that don't necessarily touch the border

Has anybody else experienced this? And do they know what can be done to prevent it?

(red spot is the extra linestring):

[image]

(zoom-in)
[image]

Comment: That's likely the call to `ST_MakeValid`. Can you share the data of your example?

Comment: What is your postgis_full_version() ? The latest release (PostGIS 3.1) use the latest GEOS 3.9 with revamped OverlayNG code wich should greatly improve spatial operations reliability and speed. See http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2020/12/waiting-postgis-31-3.html

Comment: The call to `ST_MakeValid` should not be required - the output from `ST_Difference` should always be valid.  Does the problem occur if that call is removed?

Comment: I have tried removing `St_MakeValid` and the problem still occurs.

Comment: is the short line a line of its own, or is it part of a multipart line? If there is a self intersection in the original line segment, it will be broken up in several parts (but still be a single multipart geometry)