# PostGIS - ST_Union + ST_Difference create extra line segment

Tags: postgis, polygon, intersection, union, st-difference

Very similar to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/393899/postgis-st-difference-creates-extra-line-segment)

I have two multipolygons, which touch/overalp each over. please see [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-BPVynJokeXjXTNxCpUqN3dhTtRUovkk/view?usp=sharing) for the multipolygon #1 and multipolygon #2

multipolygon #1
[image]

multipolygon #2
[image]

I ran st_union to them

```
update public.admin2_edge_match_NLD_0
set multipolygons_union = st_multi(st_union(multipolygon_1, multipolygon_2))
```

I got
[image]

I ran st_difference from the union to multipolygon #2

```
update public.admin2_edge_match_NLD_0
set diff = ST_Multi(ST_Difference(multipolygons_union, multipolygons_2))
```

I got an extra line on the output!
[image]

Comment: Seems to be a topological problem. Both polygons must share all the nodes at their boundaries where they intersect each other.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca what could be the solution for removing the extra line? Thanks

Comment: Tony, include a vertex in the multipolygon #2 boundary at any place it intersects a vertex of the multipolygon #1 boundary. If both boundaries intersects in a point without a vertex in any of them, include a vertex in both geometries. Next perform the union.

Comment: Could you share the source geometries as WKT? Even better if you bother to delete as many vertices as possible for making the WKT smaller but still showing the issue.

Comment: You could buffer them by a small value and try again.

Comment: @user30184 please see [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-BPVynJokeXjXTNxCpUqN3dhTtRUovkk/view?usp=sharing) for the multipolygon #1 and multipolygon #2

Comment: @TimothyDalton I added a very small buffer and it seems to work. Problem: if I zoom in enough, I can see a gap everywhere between diff and multipolygon_2 now

`update public.admin2_edge_match_NLD_0
set diff = ST_Multi(ST_Difference(multipolygons_union, st_buffer(multipolygons_2, 0.000001)))`

but I still do not understand why it happens. Does ST_Union have a very small floating round error, which causes multipolygons_union to become tiny larger?

Comment: @TimothyDalton the small gap is also resolved by running st_snap:

`update public.admin2_edge_match_NLD_0
set diff = st_multi(st_snap(diff, multipolygons_2, 0.000002))` Thanks

Comment: However, st_snap makes invalid polygon,s and st_makevalid will cause the edge not matched again

Comment: @Tony how is it making it invalid? Can you share the WKT's?

Comment: @TimothyDalton I have already shared the WKT in the description and comment above. actually, I have 60 such polygons, 24 of them became invalid after st_snap. Unfortunately, the WKT in the example I shared is still valid after snapping. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share a github gist where the invalidity is occuring?

Comment: @TimothyDalton [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-BPVynJokeXjXTNxCpUqN3dhTtRUovkk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Tony I played around with this a little. I think `ST_Snap` is the way to go and to make sure it works in all cases I would suggest you artificially add more vertices to your polygons that it has more leeway. Maybe start by introducing midpoints on each segment of the exteriorring. What do you think?

Comment: 1) The data from the two polygons are topologically uncorrelated, i.e. they are not combined with each other; 2) If you want to trim their whiskers, test the custom function ST_CarvesPolygons() and check your results, maybe this is what you expect...https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/333562/120129

Comment: st_buffer(geom, -0.000001) will remove the line segments